# In Swift how can I save a class object?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I create an instance of a Trie object using third party library https://github.com/fpg1503/Aho-Corasick-Swift. Example code to build Trie object is like this:

```
let trie = Trie.builder()
        .add(keyword: "hers")
        .add(keyword: "his")
        .add(keyword: "she")
        .add(keyword: "he")
        .build()
```

However, in my case number of keywords is around 300 thousand, which takes large amount of build this Trie object. My objective is build the trie object just once outside app and save it to use by App for inference on any text. Something like this:

```
let emits = trie.parse(text: "any text")
```

However, I am struggling to save this Trie object in swift. In Java (for android), I achieved this task so easily but in Swift it looks very hard thing to do. I am trying hard to achieve this using Codable but that requires all the classes starting from beginning to conform codable. I tried to copy all the codes of (https://github.com/fpg1503/Aho-Corasick-Swift) and change all classes to conform codable. My project now builds successfully but gives runtime error for encoding this Trie object:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee0005ff8)

How can I achieve this in swift?

Comment: Share your approach for android and what you tried in Swift to achieve the same? I will suggest look for a database(CoreData, RealmDB etc) to deal with such data.

Comment: If it is so easy in Java, please show us how you would do it in Java.

Comment: Why not just save the 300K keywords to a textile and load your object from that file, it shouldn't be much different than saving the object itself.

Comment: @JayLee In Java I just used ObjectOutputStream and writeObject method. Similarly, ObjectIntputStream and readObject method. Basically, you can read and write any object in a very simple way in Java

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The Trie object creation based on Aho Corsaic algorithm from keywords create a graph kind of thing and thus lot of computation goes on building this. Once it's built, it works very fast to infer from it. That's why I don't build it again in the app. I have kind of tested this hypothesis in Java(Android): If I just use the Trie object from previously created (which took around 5 minutes to created the Trie Object), the inference only takes 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: You are aware that when you use ObjectOutputStream/ObjectIntputStream in this simple manner you will not have any version control. That is if you update to a new version of Trie and the that new version has some internal changes you might not be able to read an object written with the old version. So simple yes but with a risk.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I will have to manage the object's version control by myself. I wish swift could have something like this. Getting drowned in Codable and Core data for a simple task like this doesn't make sense to me. However, it seems i don't have much choice here.

Comment: @matt The swift Aho Corsaic git repo (https://github.com/fpg1503/Aho-Corasick-Swift ) contains so many classes and structs. How could I copy whole code here. Moreover, can you feel the pain of copying the external library code and manually conforming each of them to codable? Even then, I get run time error. I am not expert like you in Swift. Your book is great but I think the real life problem like this is not addressed. In real world scenario, one would use third party library, save the object created from it.

Comment: @matt I recently found this article (https://forums.swift.org/t/why-you-cant-make-someone-elses-class-decodable-a-long-winded-explanation-of-required-initializers/6437 ). I am still trying to understand these concepts. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that State is recursive, so when you encode a State you get an infinite recursion until you generate a stack overflow.

Comment: accepting this answer as it helped me to nail down the issue which was coming from third party code (https://github.com/fpg1503/Aho-Corasick-Swift/blob/master/Source/Trie/State.swift ) : self.rootState = depth == 0 ? self : nil